# How to migrate SDL web 8.5 in Process API (java implementation) to GraphQL

Tags: graphql, pca, restfulapi

We have custom java code - sdl web 8.5 in-process API (Java) to fetch component presentations from broker DB and serve it to web application.

1. What does it need to migrate this implementation to GraphQL.
2. Is there any sample implementation code (java) for reference.

Online I found lots of details about GraphiQL Queries execution in Browser but unable to find any details on GraphQL API code implementation or samples for same. Any one has any pointers on same, please share. Thanks

Comment: Did you try doing a generic search for the GraphQL java samples not specific to Tridion?

Comment: Have you set up a GraphQL client for Java yet? I suspect you should start with that and get to the simplest request and go from there. Your question is definitely interesting to anyone starting with GraphQL in the context of Tridion Sites for the first time. However, the scope of migration and samples is too broad to answer definitively. Start with setting up your client and definitely ask questions along the way!

Comment: @Gulshan, Please clarify are you looking for graphql in sites 8.5? please note that graphql only supported from sites 9.0+